# Multiple Layer-In-Folder Editing

Tags: photoshop

So basically i have 10 copies of the same folder in 10 other seperate folders, and i want to edit the contents of the folders all at once.

All i want to do is move 2 layers to a different location for every single folder i have. How would i go about doing this?

Would anyone recommend batch or anything? and if so, it would be cool if someone could help and tell me how to do the required process too. Thank you.

Edit:
So for some reason my question is not going through so im going to assume i need more text or something so please dont read this as this is just random text im adding for no reason. im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if all the images and colors are same in the folders 
then change one folder and duplicate in 10 times 
as per your question i not fully understand 
you have to provide some more information 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Use Smart Objects next time.
Now:

1. Convert folder in to Smart Object and dublicate in necessary location.
2. Edit Smart Object contents.